# I am converting Date in mysql query its not working with str_to_date?

Tags: php, mysql

I am converting Date in Mysql query. It's saved in varchar in database in this format 10-January-2015. I am converting it to year-month-date 2015-01-10. 
I have used `str_to_date(myfield, '%d-%M-%Y')`, and `date_format(myfield, '%d-%M-%Y'),` but it shows no rows.

The query I'm writing shows no rows yet it works when I give exact date in string.

```
SELECT * FROM table where str_to_date(date, '%d-%M-%Y') = '20-June-2015';
```

Comment: you should better change your schema and store correct type in column `date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mysql `Date_Format`

```
Date_Format(date, '%d-%M-%Y')
```

use query like taht:-

```
SELECT * FROM table where Date_Format(date, '%d-%M-%Y') = '20-June-2015';
```

Or use `str_to_date` like that :-

```
SELECT * FROM table where date= str_to_date('20-June-2015', '%d-%M-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny answer, but I guess it is correct :-) :

Since *its saved in var char* you don't need any casting functions there just:

```
SELECT * FROM table where `date` = '20-June-2015';
```

Comment: @FirstOne Sure it will not. but why?